# Property header for firebase auth token api request to a custom server

Tags: rest, http, firebase-authentication, http-headers

I have a project including both a frontend (made with Vue) and a backend (made with Node.js). My **server** handles **all the frontend requests** and has **its own mongodb**. I am using **firebase only for the authentications**.

My problem is this: how can I make the server sure that a certain request is sent by a logged in user that has the privilege to do that request?

For instance if I have the request `POST /user/:uid/products`, that makes a user add a product to its account, I want to be sure that it was the actual user that made this request.

I came up with this: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens#web, getting the user token from the frontend and checking it in the server through the firebase admin api.

I just want to know **which is the right header** where I should put this token. I mean, should the frontend put the created token in the "Authorization" header? Which header is the most appropriate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's customary to put it in the "Authorization" header, just as you said.

Typically the header is formatted like this:

```
Authorization: Bearer <token>
```

This is documented in the [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Framework: Bearer Token Usage, section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6750#section-2.1).  Your backend should of course parse the same format.